# Recognizing several IDs in a complicated String with R

Tags: string, r

I have a data frame with a lot of character strings and a value like this

```
ID String                                                    Value
1  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32    100
2  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321                         50
3  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32                          120
...
```

As you may see in the example, the "," means "or". So locationID=123,321,345 refers to those elements that have location ID 123, 321, or 345. and the "value" can be thought as the numbers of entries that satisfied the String.

I want to write a program to calculate the number of occurrences of each ID using R. i.e. the output of the program should be:

```
ID                Occurrence
LocationID = 123  270                          #(100+50+120)
LocationID = 321  220                          #(100+120)
...
TypeID = 12       100
...
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to do this task?

I found it is very difficult to deal with the "," and the IDs. Otherwise I can use for loop, though I hate for loop.....

A further problem, the ID should allow empty or character, like this:

```
ID String                                                    Value
1  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=         100
2  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=&TypeID=A                       50
3  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32                          120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G. Grothendieck's answer is *much* nicer, but since I had already started working on a solution, here it is. This sticks to base R and involves a long `lapply`. Assuming your data is named "mydata":

First, split the "String" column by the ampersand

```
temp1 <- strsplit(mydata$String, "&")
```

Second, here's a complicated anonymous function called in `lapply`. I've annotated the steps so you can see what's happening.

```
temp2 <- do.call(
  "rbind", 
  lapply(seq_along(temp1), function(x) {
    # Set the pattern we're going to look for
    pattern <- "(.*)=(.*)"
    # Extract names and values
    Name <- gsub(pattern, "\\1", temp1[[x]])
    Measure <- gsub(pattern, "\\2", temp1[[x]])
    # Split the Measure value, and create a data.frame
    Output <- lapply(strsplit(Measure, ","), function(x) 
      data.frame(as.numeric(x)))
    names(Output) <- Name             # Add the names back to the list
    Output <- do.call(rbind, Output)  # rbind the sub-lists
    # Move the rownames to a column
    Output$Param <- gsub("(.*)\\.[0-9]+", "\\1", rownames(Output))
    rownames(Output) <- NULL          # Clean up the rownames
    names(Output)[1] <- "Measure"     # Rename the measure variable
    # Make a nice dataframe with your original data too.
    data.frame(ID = mydata[x, "ID"], Output, Value = mydata[x, "Value"])
  }))
```

The result looks like this:

```
temp2
#    ID Measure      Param Value
# 1   1     123 LocationID   100
# 2   1     321 LocationID   100
# 3   1     345 LocationID   100
# 4   1     456     TimeID   100
# 5   1     321     TimeID   100
# 6   1     789     TimeID   100
# 7   1      12     TypeID   100
# 8   1      32     TypeID   100
# 9   2     123 LocationID    50
# 10  2     345 LocationID    50
# 11  2     456     TimeID    50
# 12  2     321     TimeID    50
# 13  3     123 LocationID   120
# 14  3     321 LocationID   120
# 15  3     345 LocationID   120
# 16  3      32     TypeID   120
```

So, now we can easily use `aggregate` on the output to get this:

```
aggregate(Value ~ Param + Measure, temp2, sum)
#        Param Measure Value
# 1     TypeID      12   100
# 2     TypeID      32   220
# 3 LocationID     123   270
# 4 LocationID     321   220
# 5     TimeID     321   150
# 6 LocationID     345   270
# 7     TimeID     456   150
# 8     TimeID     789   100
```

---

For convenience, here's a `dput` of the first few lines of your data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, 
                         String = c("LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32",
                                    "LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321", 
                                    "LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32"), 
                         Value = c(100L, 50L, 120L)), 
                    .Names = c("ID", "String", "Value"), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                    class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I have used your suggestions as it is easier to be modified to fix my further data requirement, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  `lapply2` is like `lapply` except that it rbind's the result afterwards.  We split up the String argument and put the result in `s` .  Then we calculate a new data frame `dat2` that has one row for each ID.  For the sample data there are 3 IDs in row 1, 2 IDs in row 2 and 2 IDs in row 3 so `dat2` has 3+2+2 = 7 rows.  In a similar manner we explode `dat2` to produce `dat3` .  As part of that we use `strapplyc` to simplify extracting all the Occurrences. Finally we use `aggregate` to compute the result.

```
library(gsubfn)

lapply2 <- function(...) do.call("rbind", lapply(...))

s <- strsplit(dat$String, "&")

dat2 <- lapply2(1:nrow(dat), function(i) 
     data.frame(
            String = I(s[[i]]), 
            Value = dat$Value[i]
     )
)

dat3 <- lapply2(1:nrow(dat2), function(i) 
     data.frame(
            String = sub("=.*", "", dat2$String[i]), 
            Occurrence = strapplyc(dat2$String[i], "\\d+")[[1]], 
            Value = dat2$Value[i]
     )
)

ag <- aggregate(Value ~ String + Occurrence, dat3, sum)
```

The result is:

```
> ag
      String Occurrence Value
1 LocationID        123   270
2 LocationID        321   220
3     TimeID        321   150
4 LocationID        345   270
5     TimeID        456   150
6     TimeID        789   100
7     TypeID         12   100
8     TypeID         32   220
```

Comment: Thank you very much, But can you further give me some suggestion, if the data allow this format?

    ID String                                                    Value
    1  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=         100
    2  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=&TypeID=a                       50
    3  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32                          120

Which is the IDs can be a string or can be empty

Comment: `dat2$String` will end in a `=` for empty right hand sides so just remove those rows: `dat2 <- dat2[!grepl("=$", dat2$String), ]`

Answer (score 1):

try using strsplit function, you can tokenize your strings like so

```
strsplit("LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32","&"); ## this will tokenize by splitting by &;
```

Then use grep to determine the presence of LocationID,TimeID,TypeID and suitably strsplit by '=' and then ',' appending the values into an auxiliary frame.

finally call a 'tapply'

Hope this helps as a broad outline

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'ID String                                                    Value
1  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32    100
2  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321                         50
3  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32                          120',header= T, stringsAsFactors=F)
## split by &
ll <- unlist(strsplit(dat$String,'&'))
## create 2 lits of occuonces and id names
occs <- strsplit(gsub('(.*)ID=(.*)','\\2',ll),',')
ids <- gsub('(.*)ID=(.*)','\\1',ll)
names(occs) <- ids
ll <- sapply(names(occs),function(x) occs[x] <- paste(x,occs[[x]], sep ='_'))
## use rapply to change list in data.frame then count by table
table(rapply(ll,I))

Location_123 Location_321 Location_345     Time_321     Time_456     Time_789      Type_12      Type_32 
           3            3            3            2            2            2            2            2
```