# Counting Difference ID and calculate the co-existence in a lot of String

Tags: r

This is a followup of one of my previous question, hope you can help me
The previous questions:
[Recognizing several IDs in a complicated String with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700118/recognizing-several-ids-in-a-complicated-string-with-r)

I have a data frame with a lot of character strings and a value like this

```
ID String                                                    Value
1  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32    100
2  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321                         50
3  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32                          120
...
```

The String can also be like this, where the ID should allow empty or character, like this:

```
ID String                                                    Value
11  LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=         100
12  LocationID=123,345&TimeID=&TypeID=A                       50
13  LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32   
...
```

As you may see in the example, the "," means "or". So locationID=123,321,345 refers to those elements that have location ID 123, 321, or 345. and the "value" can be thought as the numbers of entries that satisfied the String.

I want to write a program to count the number of occurrences of some specific ID using R. i.e. the output of the program should be:

```
sID  LocationID    TimeID    TypeID
1             3         3         2   #(String ID 1 have 3 Locaiotn ID, 3 TimeID and 2 TypeID)
2             2         2         0
...
```

I have also need to calculate the co-existence of two different ID, like

```
Condition          Co_existence
Location-Time               0.9   # How likely that I find a TimeID in the String, I will find a Location ID
Type-Time                   0.8   # How likely that I find a TimeID in the String, I will find a Type ID
......
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to do there two?

Comment: Maybe I miss something but in what this is different from your previous [question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700118/recognizing-several-ids-in-a-complicated-string-with-r)

Comment: The previous one is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700118/recognizing-several-ids-in-a-complicated-string-with-r
I think the most different things are:
1) the previous I count the IDs across all strings
2) This one I need to count within the strings and need the co-existency.

As my understanding, this one and the last one could be worked on different approaches, that is why I ask again

Comment: And this time I dont really care about the specific ID number, but how many IDs of the same type are existed in the same string

Comment: I think you don't get my point. Last time you ask about splitting a data.frame according to some criteria. You get some very nice answers!Why you come back here with the same structure? The  simple answer is that you have used the code of others without taking the time to understand it! So for me all this is very localized and I will upvote to close this question.

Comment: @KloserCheung, perhaps to clarify agstudy's point, it would have been nicer if you'd show what **you have done so far** and where you got stuck. As of now, there isn't any evidence of you making an attempt (for an almost same problem).

Comment: Since you've asked for suggestions, @oscar's answer gives you a place to start really nicely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would go as in the previous question:

- Split for each string
- Split each string into its components
- Collect IDs, string names and components into a dataframe

**Example code:**

```
# Beter share example data this way (directly usable in R)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13), stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 String = c("LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32",
                            "LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321",
                            "LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32",
                            "LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=",
                            "LocationID=123,345&TimeID=&TypeID=A",
                            "LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32"),
                 Values = c(100, 50, 120, 100, 50, NA))

# Get each String component in a list
df$splitString <- strsplit(df$String, split='&')

## Identify each String with the record ID before further processing
## (we will collect them out of the dataframe)
names(df$splitString) <- df$ID

# Split each component on [=, ] (*i.e.* split wherever there is an equal sign,
# a comma or a space). The first element is the name of the String, and the
# next elements are each possible value for it.
df$splitStringValues <- lapply(X=df$splitString, FUN=strsplit, split='[=, ]+')

# Be sure to explore the structure that we've got so far
str(df)
```

Next create a dataframe with the following variables:

- ID: the original ID
- StringName: the names of the different strings (*e.g.* LocationID, TimeID, *etc.*)
- StringValue: the possible values for each string.

From this dataframe you should be able to get all the information you wanted.

---

**Edit:** As suggested by Arun, I completed the requested analysis. Why should the OP get any fun? I added one step and modified the data, so check that too. New code bellow:

```
# Processing the list is much easier with plyr
library(package=plyr)

# You take the list of strings, and for each string get the values
# (all but the first, which is the name of the string), record the
# name of the string for each value, and collect everything in a dataframe.
# For empty strings set NA.
strings <- ldply(.data=df$splitStringValues,
                 .fun=function(record){
                    ldply(.data=record,
                          .fun=function(string){
                             if(length(string)>1){
                                .tmp <- data.frame(Val=string[-1])
                                .tmp <- cbind(String=string[1], .tmp)
                             } else {
                                .tmp <- data.frame(Val=NA, String=string[1])
                             }
                             .tmp
                     })
            })

# Count values in each string
table(strings$String, strings$.id)

# And calculate co-ocurrence.
co_ocurrence <-
   ddply(.data=strings, .variables='.id',
         .fun=function(x){
           data.frame(Combinations=combn(unique(x$String), m=2, paste, collapse='-'))
   })
prop.table(table(co_ocurrence$Combinations))
```

Comment: +1 for the 'presenting data the correct way' tutorial.

Comment: :) thanks. Suggesting `dump('df', file='')` would have been better, but it seemed like an overkill this time (and possibly would not have been well received/perceived ;).

Comment: (+1) @OscardeLeón, nice post so far, but I feel like the part you've left out is perhaps equally important. You've split alright. Now, how do you count within the splits? (as they may have one or more ID types missing)

Comment: There @Arun, ready. I just didn't want to spoil the fun for Kloser. I used plyr though, since it would have been messier with base R functions.

Comment: @OscardeLeón, yes, I totally understand and think it's a nice approach to let some pieces for the OP. I realised it after writing that the OP also was looking for pointers. Anyhoo, great job!

Comment: @OscardeLeón, Thank you for your advises, but I find your code will count those ID with empty value as 1, i.e. count of ID2 in this line "ID1=123&ID2=&ID3=456", finally I amended a little bit and the problem solved: .tmp <- data.frame(Val=NA, String=NA)

Comment: @KloserCheung yes, I was counting all IDs that appeared, whether they ha values or not (*i.e.* if an ID is present, the minimum times it gets counted is 1). The values for each ID, on the other hand, ranged indeed from 0 to whatever number of them appeared. Great you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your invaluable comments and advises. Finally I have used the following codes to get my task done.

I am not a good programmer, and mostly can only use some brute force algorithm to deal with my problem. I am always like to ask for experts like you guys to learn some smarter way on my work.

And I am very new to R, I think. I am always confused by the concepts of "list", "dataframe", ... and also the lapply, mapply, ... And it is even worse when the problem involves RegEx...
That is my very honor to have all of you giving advises to me in the Stack Overflow Society.

I do think I have learn a lot from you guys

The Following is the final codes I used to work on my real data, Please give me your advises again if you have some smarter way.

Thanks again and again.

```
##### Clear things to start #####
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

#### Testing Data Frame ####
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13), stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             String = c("LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=12,32&DummyID=969",
                        "LocationID=123,345&TimeID=456,321&DummyID=969",
                        "LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32&DummyID=969",
                        "LocationID=123,321,345&TimeID=456,321,789&TypeID=&DummyID=969",
                        "LocationID=123,345&TimeID=&TypeID=A&DummyID=969",
                        "LocationID=123,321,345&TypeID=32&DummyID=969"),
             Values = c(100, 50, 120, 100, 50, NA))
# The wanted IDs
fields <- c("LocationID", "TimeID", "TypeID")
outFile <- "./Co_occurence.xlsx"

#### Main Program ####
# Get each String component in a list
df$splitString <- strsplit(df$String, split='&')

## Identify each String with the record ID before further processing
## (we will collect them out of the dataframe)
names(df$splitString) <- df$ID

# Split each component on [=, ] (*i.e.* split wherever there is an equal sign,
# a comma or a space). The first element is the name of the String, and the
# next elements are each possible value for it.
df$splitStringValues <- lapply(X=df$splitString, FUN=strsplit, split='[=, ]+')

# Processing the list is much easier with plyr
library(package=plyr)

# You take the list of strings, and for each string get the values
# (all but the first, which is the name of the string), record the
# name of the string for each value, and collect everything in a dataframe.
# For empty strings set NA.
strings <- ldply(.data=df$splitStringValues,
             .fun=function(record){
               ldply(.data=record,
                     .fun=function(string){
                       if(length(string)>1){
                         .tmp <- data.frame(Val=string[-1])
                         .tmp <- cbind(String=string[1], .tmp)
                       } else {
                         # Set String = NA if Value is Empty
                         # Otherwise will get 1 for entries like ID2 in "ID1=123&ID2=&ID3=456"
                         .tmp <- data.frame(Val=NA, String=NA)
                       }
                       .tmp
                     })
             })

# Remove those unwanted IDs
finalStrings <- strings[strings$String %in% fields,]
finalStrings$String <- factor(finalStrings$String)

# Count values in each string
OutStrings <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(finalStrings$.id, finalStrings$String))
OutStrings$ID <- rownames(OutStrings)
OutStrings <- merge(df[,c("ID", "String", "Values")], 
                OutStrings, by="ID")
OutStrings$Total <- rowSums(OutStrings[,4:ncol(OutStrings)],)
OutStrings$nFields<- rowSums(OutStrings[,4:ncol(OutStrings)]!=0,)
OutStrings <- OutStrings[with(OutStrings, order(-OutStrings$Value)), ]

# Count the total occurrence for different number of conditions used
OutDistrTotal <- aggregate(Values~Total, sum, data=OutStrings)
OutDistrTotal <- OutDistrTotal[with(OutDistrTotal, order(-OutDistrTotal$Values)),]

# Count the total occurrence for different number of Fields used
OutDistrnFields <- aggregate(Values~nFields, sum, data=OutStrings)
OutDistrnFields <- OutDistrnFields[with(OutDistrnFields, order(-OutDistrnFields$Values)),]

# And calculate co-ocurrence.
co_ocurrence <- ddply(.data=finalStrings, .variables='.id',
    .fun=function(x){
      data.frame(Combinations=combn(unique(x$String), m=2, paste, collapse='-'))
    })
Outcooccurrence <- data.frame(prop.table(table(co_ocurrence$Combinations)))
Outcooccurrence <- Outcooccurrence[with(Outcooccurrence, order(-Outcooccurrence$Freq)),]

library("xlsx")
write.xlsx(OutStrings, outFile, "Strings", append=F, row.names = FALSE)
write.xlsx(OutDistrTotal, outFile, "DistrTotal", append=T, row.names = FALSE)
write.xlsx(OutDistrnFields, outFile, "OutDistrnFields", append=T, row.names = FALSE)
write.xlsx(Outcooccurrence, outFile, "Outcooccurrence", append=T, row.names = FALSE)
```